# Not Able To Get X & Y of Added Marker by Click

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps Api 3 I am able to add marker to map but coudlnt figure it out how to get lat and long of the added pont

I tried

```
   console.log(e.latLng);
   console.log(marker.position);
   console.log(marker.getPosition());
   console.log(marker.position.x);
   console.log(marker.position.lat);
```

but none of them returned the x or y

```
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
    console.log(e.latLng);
});

function placeMarker(position, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        draggable:true,
        map: map
    });
  console.log(marker.position);
}
```

Comment: what is e in this case? I'm referring to console.log(e.latlng). I would think marker.position.latlng would do it.

Comment: I actually test the `console.log(e.latLng);` at `map.addListener('click', function(e) {});` level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the lattitude use:

```
marker.position.lat();
```

and to get the longitude use

```
marker.position.lng();
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ControlPosition